# How to handle error thrown by React.lazy component?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I hava a function that load component dynamiclly below:

```
export const loader = (file: string) => {
  let pagePath = file.replace(/^views/, 'pages');
  pagePath = pagePath.replace(/\/index$/, '');

  const LazyComponent = lazy(
    () =>
      import(
        /* webpackChunkName: "dynamic_page" */ `@/${pagePath}/index.tsx`
      ),
  );

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
      <LazyComponent />
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export const Loader: React.FC<{ path: string }> = ({ path }) => {
  return (
    <ErrorBoundary>
      {loader(path)}
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
};
```

When passed wrong path, dynamic import part throw error:

```
caught Error: Cannot find module './pages/modules/info/priceConfig/index.tsx'
```

Why is the error not handled by ErrorBoundary component? And if I want to catch it and return a default component, how?

Answer (score 7):

> Why is the error not handled by ErrorBoundary component?

The ErrorBoundary handles errors thrown within the React component tree during rendering, lifecycle methods. It does not catch errors thrown within asynchronous code, such as Promises.

A workaround was suggested here:
https://eddiewould.com/2021/28/28/handling-rejected-promises-error-boundary-react/

Solution for your problem:

```
const LazyComponent = lazy(() =>
    import...).catch(
      (error) => {
        console.error("Component Failed Loading:", error);
        return { default: FallbackComponent };
      }
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

To properly handle errors when working with `React.lazy` you need to use a combination of different elements:

a) use a `.catch()` to handle the async errors (eg: network issues). 
**IMPORTANT**: that `.catch()` function has to return a `{default: jsx}` because, after handling an error with the `.catch()`, the promise resolves successfully and in the context of React.lazy, a "default exported React component" is then expected to prevent the application from crashing or displaying incomplete content.

b) use `<ErrorBoundary fallback..>` to handle rendering or lifecycle errors. [Reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-error-boundary).

c) use `<Suspense fallback..>` to handle the loading state (when the lazy loading promise is pending). [Reference](https://react.dev/reference/react/Suspense)

Good Example:

```
import React from "react";

const Root = () => {

    const ImageGallery = React.lazy(() =>
       //.catch() use example
        import('./components/ImageGallery').catch((error) => {
            console.error('Failed to load ImageGallery:', error);
            //mandatory return
            return { default: () => <div>Error loading the component.</div> }; 
        })
    );


    return (
        <ErrorBoundary fallback={<div>Something went wrong</div>}>
            <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading component...</div>}>
                <ImageGallery />
            </Suspense>
        </ErrorBoundary>
    );
}
```

Note: It’s also a good practice to add some retry logic for the lazy import.